# Remove " and =+ from cells in Google Sheets

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, substitution

I have cells like

```
"Apple"
=+Organe +is +good
"Mango"
```

I want to remove all the characters i.e. `=` and `"`  and `+`

Tried `=SUBSTITUTE(C3,"+" ,"",1)` but didnt work

I am using Google Sheets and **can't** use Excel (in MAC)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If you know which and how many characters should be removed** N nested substitutes would work. Just make sure that the input cell is not an error:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"="," "),"+"," "),"""","")
```

[image]

**If you need** to exclude anything but the alphabet characters A to Z and the numbers from 0 to 9, VBA + RegEx come into power:

[image]

```
Public Function RemoveNonAlphabetChars(inputString As String) As String

    Dim regEx           As Object
    Dim inputMatches    As Object
    Dim regExString     As String

    Set regEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

    With regEx
        .Global = True
        .Pattern = "[^a-zA-Z0-9]"
        .ignoreCase = True
        Set inputMatches = .Execute(inputString)

        If regEx.test(inputString) Then
            RemoveNonAlphabetChars = .Replace(inputString, vbNullString)
        Else
            RemoveNonAlphabetChars = inputString
        End If
    End With

End Function
```

Comment: its not picking up strings like =+article +writing +services +dubai

Comment: @user3415869 - that one gives an error in Excel, and it is not a good practice to pass an error as a parameter to a function. Anyway, either try the VBA option or write string like `'=+article +writing +services +dubai`, which would not be error and would work, because of teh `'` in the beginning of the string.

Comment: Thanks, I dont use excel, I should have tagged google sheet vba. any chance it can work on google sheet vba?

Comment: @user3415869 - never tried google sheet vba. But give it a try, worst case it will not work :D

Comment: @user3415869 - not your lucky day I guess.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(A1:A, "[=\+""]", ))
```

[image: 0]

---

or if you want to use `SUBSTITUTE` then:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1:A, "=", ), "+", ), """", ))
```

[image: 0]